# jQueryUI toggle in a dialog box

Tags: jquery, user-interface, toggle, dialog

Would be possible to add inside of a dialog box a toggle window? The dialog box opens and clicking inside of a link would slide down a form. So one I have the dialog box

```
$('a.open_dialog').click(function() {
    $('<div />').appendTo('body').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
        title: $(this).attr('title'),
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        width: 800,
        position: 'top'            
    });
    return false;
});
```

and I would like to have inside

```
$('a.mailer').click(function() {
    $('#contact-wrapper').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic contents use jquery on():

```
$('a.mailer').on('click',function() {
   $('#contact-wrapper').show();
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery **1.7**, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Comment: Examples:

`$(selector).live(events, data, handler);`                // jQuery 1.3+
`$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);`  // jQuery 1.4.3+
`$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);`        // jQuery 1.7+